# How arrays and objects are mutable and string, numbers and all the primitive data types are immutable?

Tags: javascript

How arrays and objects are mutable but string, numbers and all the primitive data types are immutable?

```js
var a = 'priya';
a = 'puja';
```

Is this immutable ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. In _"Is this immutable"_, what is **"this"**?

Comment: You probably need to make up your mind about what *immutable* means.

Comment: variable a is mutable or immutable

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Mutable this will be helpful